# Spl_autoload_register file not found

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to autoload classes but spl_autoload register is not finding the file and I am getting file not found error.

My file structure:

```
index.php
system/
    configs/
      config.php
    messages/
      message.php
    user/
      user.php
```

So here is what I am doing.

config.php

I got the below function from another answer

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {

# Usually I would just concatenate directly to $file variable below
# this is just for easy viewing on Stack Overflow)
    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $dir = __DIR__;

// replace namespace separator with directory separator (prolly not required)
    $className = str_replace('\\', $ds, $className);

// get full name of file containing the required class
    $file = "{$dir}{$ds}{$className}.php";

   require_once $file;
});

use system\user\user;

$obj = new User();
```

user.php

```
namespace system\user;
class user{
   ...
}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\System\Configs\System\User\User.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$file = "{$dir}{$ds}{$className}.php";
```

with

```
$file = "{$dir}/../../{$ds}{$className}.php";
```

so that your root dir is `system/` instead of `system/configs/`

Comment: doesn't work. `Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\System\Configs/../../\System\User\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: `System\User\Exception.php` exists?

Comment: I don't have that file

Comment: That's another problem. How do you call that class in your code?

Comment: I was extending the exception class so added backslash to the front and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is at:
user/user.php

but your autoloader is looking for:
User/User.php

This is because when you instantiate $obj = new User(); then your $className in the autoloader has become "User".

Change:
$className = strtolower(str_replace('\', $ds, $className));

Or change your dir structure to:
User/User.php

Comment: It might seem strange, but windows is case insensitive